# Маленькие проблемы в отправки данных с помощью axios

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, axios

У меня не получается отправлять данные, методом `POST`, с помощью `axios`, и я просто не понимаю где у меня ошибка, либо ошибка в отправки данных на php код, либо проблемы уже при отправки данных **из** php в БД. Что именно у меня происходит: в `input login` я ввожу значения, которые проверяются в БД (если есть данный логин, то появляется ошибка), пишу, например, "user" (и такой логин у меня уже есть в БД), и он выдает ошибку, пишу уже "User", и все-равно выдает ошибку, как будто у меня есть этот логин с этой заглавной буквой в началe.
Вот мой код:

```
check_login(){
                return axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    url: 'check.php',
                    data: {
                        login: this.login
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.error = response.data.login;
                    return this.error;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
```

А вот и php код:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$login = $_POST->login;
include_once('settings.php');
$sql_login = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_login);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row)
    $_POST->{'login'} = true;
else    
    $_POST->{'login'} = false;
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: Проверьте, что приходит от php скрипта в js. Возможно вместо false приходит строка "false", которая с точки зрения приведения типов всегда будет true

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, но тогда бы у меня совсем ничего не работало, а так у меня хоть немного и не правильно, но тем не менее работает, у меня в php коде все нормально проверяется на наличие логина, но почему-то он возвращает true даже тогда, когда начальная/любая другая буква заглавная, и а не понимаю почему так происходит (извини за мой порченный русский, плохо составляю предложения...)